# How to access a variable from ajax success from within another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

check_promo is an ajax function and parameter 'param' is from ajax success. How do I want to call that parameter to be processed in the next function?

I tried to display alerts but it did not match the resulting ajax

```
function result_promo(){
    var data = '';
    check_promo(function(param){ //output param is 1
        data = param;
    });
    return data ;
}

function submit(){
    var check = result_promo();
    alert(check); //not showing 1 but null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function result_promo(){
    var data = '';
    check_promo(function(param){ //output param is 1
        submit(param);
    });
    return data ;
}

function submit(param){
    var check = param;
    alert(check); //It will show 1 in alert box
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise to archive this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Since `check_promo` is making an AJAX call and the parameter passed to it is a callback, what's happening is that you're firing off the AJAX function but `result_promo` returns before `check_promo` to complete. Hence `data` is `null`.

Instead, you'd be better off calling `check_promo` in `submit`. The `result_promo` function serves no real purpose here.

Comment: so, how should i make

Comment: Call `check_promo` inside `submit`, the way you do in `result_promo`. And put the `alert` in the callback function.

Comment: but the result of the callback function I need to do the next process in another function

Comment: Then you'll have to pass a callback to that function and pass that up to `check_promo`. Or you can read about and use (and return) promises.

Answer (score 0):

If your function ' check_promo' is used AJAX call then you need to use Promise or Observable for getting the latest res.

For more information, please follow :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable